# How to import/merge data from from 2 separate sheets from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I need to import data from "Spreadsheet A" to "Spreadsheet B" but all the data is in two separate sheets "MY" and "NY" in "Spreadsheet A"

I basically need exactly this but with a function to import from another spreadsheet, not only within the same one

```
=QUERY({{ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(QUERY(MY!A2:A; "select A where A is not null")))))\QUERY(MY!A2:A; "select A where A is not null")};  {ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(QUERY(NY!A2:A; "select A where A is not null")))))\QUERY(NY!A2:A; "select A where A is not null")}}; "select Col2 order by Col1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first, run one **`IMPORTRRANGE`** to connect the sheets:

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "MY!A2")
  ```
- then try:

  ```
  =QUERY({{ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "MY!A2:A"); "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")))))\
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "MY!A2:A"); "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")};
          {ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "NY!A2:A"); "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")))))\
   QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "NY!A2:A"); "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")}}; 
  "select Col2 order by Col1")
  ```

  [image: 0]
- also make sure that both spreadsheets have the same amount of rows

Comment: this formula outputs #REF! in two separate cells below each other withot any error message

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: Sheet A (source of data) [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RU9idUVllVXAP0DXe5UHWbCVbqJol_YRKg6sGdQTi48/edit#gid=0)

Sheet B (where the data should be imported and merged) [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11TldgbSU1OIYPV73L-To7cnScpdPdKJhoPo6bMgnREo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @MarekMarhoul answer and your sheet updated

Comment: sweet! Thank you, as always great work